# spring dependency injection is not working in a class annotated with @WebListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, servlet-listeners

I tried constructor based Dependency injection in TestAppListener class which implements ServletContextListener.
I got this error
**Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.example.listener.TestAppListener]**.

I searched stack overflow but I couldn't find any solution for this scenario. Please any one help me in sort out this. I placed Implementation classes in META-INF.services folder also. My understanding is there is some problem in constructor dependency injection but this way of DI is need for my situation, because in real time I want to create datasource connection inside startup method.

Find all my classes below which i'm using,

```
@WebListener
public class TestAppListener implements ServletContextListener {

private static TestDao dao;

public TestAppListener(TestDao dao){
    this.dao = dao;
}
public TestAppListener(){}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    dao = ServiceLoader.load(TestDao.class).iterator().next();
    dao.startUp();
    System.out.println("Context initialized method called");
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    System.out.println("Context destroyed method called");
    dao.shutDown();
}
```

}

```
public interface TestDao {

void startUp();

void shutDown();
```

}

```
public class TestDaoImpl implements TestDao {
@Override
public void startUp() {
    System.out.println("Database is initialized");
}

@Override
public void shutDown() {
    System.out.println("Database is initialized");
}
```

}

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

public SpringConfig() {
}

@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> listenerRegistrationBean() {
    ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> bean = new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>();
    bean.setListener(new TestAppListener());
    return bean;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The Servlet `@WebListener`s are handled by Servlet containers(tomcat/Jetty) when the container is starting. So they know nothing about Spring.

For more details, see [discussion in this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25059).

A workaround solution is replace the `@WebListener` with Spring's `@Component`, thus you can inject Spring beans(declare your Dao as spring beans) into the listeners directly.

BTW, you have to add `@ServletComponentScan` on your Spring Boot application class to activate it.

I created [an example project](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/servlet) to demo `@WebServlet`, `@WebFilter` and `@WebListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `private static TestDao dao` to `private final TestDao dao`. Spring doesn't allow statics to be used as targets for injection. Also, your `TestDaoImpl` class needs to be a component or a bean defined in a Spring configuration file.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason causing the issue., as it is not injecting static field via spring injection. Though not recommended.